# Prove discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The definition of discontinuity i'm using is "not continuous" (nothing to do with jump discontinuities etc.).
Let $g:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$g(x)=|x|^{1/2}\sin(\frac{1}{\sin x}), x \ne n\pi$$ and $g(n\pi)=0$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I want to show that g is discontinuous at all $n\pi$. I've tried showing $\lim_{x \to n\pi}g(x) \ne 0$ by constructing different sequences along the lines of $x_i=n\pi+\frac{1}{i}$ but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. I've also tried directly using the inverse of the epsilon delta definition i.e $\exists \varepsilon >0 \text{ s.t } \forall \delta >0 \exists x \text{ with } |x-n\pi|<\delta \text{ but } |g(x)|>\varepsilon$ but similarly no luck.

Comment: Try the sequences $2/(\pi(1+4k))$ and $2/(\pi(3+4k))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit ugly but more of a follow your nose proof (something where you fix the proof as you go)

Continue the strategy of $n \pi + \frac{1}{i}$ but instead of getting $(-1)^n \sin \frac{1}{i}$ for the innermost $\sin$ change the sequence $\frac{1}{i}$ to $\sin y_i$ where $y_i$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$ approaching $0$. Continue this way

$$
g(x) = \mid x \mid^{1/2} \sin \bigg( \frac{1}{\sin x} \bigg)\\
x_i = n \pi + \sin^{-1} y_i\\
y_i \to 0\\
g(x_i) = \mid x_i \mid^{1/2} \sin \bigg( \frac{1}{(-1)^n y_i} \bigg)\\
y_i = \frac{1}{z_i}\\
z_i \to +\infty\\
g(x_i) = \mid x_i \mid^{1/2} (-1)^n \sin z_i\\
$$

So in total use $x_i = n \pi + \sin^{-1} \frac{1}{z_i}$ for some sequence $z_i$ approaching $+\infty$. Pick this sequence judiciously. For example, if $z_i = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2i\pi - (-1)^i \pi$ then you get $g(x_i) = \mid x_i \mid^{1/2} (-1)^{i+n}$ which has two accumulation points $\pm \mid n \pi \mid$ when $n \neq 0$.

You can continue from this sketch.